# How must we understand verses 74:42-47?

Tags: quran, tafseer

In Sura Al-Muddaththir (74) there is a conversation between people of Jannah and people of Jahannam. The people of Jannah will ask the people of Jahannam about the reason for their being in Jahannam. And people of Jahannam will reply:

> 42."What put you into Saqar?"
> 43.They will say, "We were not of those who prayed,
> 44.Nor did we used to feed the poor.
> 45.And we used to enter into vain discourse with those who engaged [in it],
> 46.And we used to deny the Day of Recompense
> 47.Until there came to us the certainty."

So, simply saying the people of Jahannam are counting the actions they committed in life which caused them to be put into Saqar (Jahannam). My question is "**is it only one of these actions which will cause a person to be put into Saqar** OR **a person should commit all of these actions in order to be put into Saqar?**".

Although each verse is starting with union "and", which gives a meaning that a person should commit all of these actions in order to be put into Saqar, some scholars are using this way of understanding the verses to justify, for example, not praying. That is, praying is not necessary if a person is giving charity, and vice versa, the person will enter Jannah this way. And based on this, in some situations, those scholars are even making a dangerous claim that "a person who IS NOT praying IS NOT kafeer".

---

**Edit:**

So there are 2 interpretations:

1. Committing only one of these actions will cause a person to be put into
   Saqar.
2. Committing all of these actions will cause a person to be put into
   Saqar.

I believe that 1st view is correct and the only evidence I have found that supports this view is verse 2:208

> O you who have believed, enter into Islam completely [and perfectly]
> and do not follow the footsteps of Satan. Indeed, he is to you a clear
> enemy.

Anyway, I'd like to see other opinions or views of scholars

Comment: Who are these "some scholars" you refer to?

Comment: Actually the question is about understanding the verses, not about scholars. The problem is those "some scholars" are interpreting these verses for a specific goals, like to justify not praying or not giving charity.

Answer (score 2):

Salam alaikoum,
I am far from being a mufti, but to understand these verses, we must know that a Muslim is called among other things to pray, to feed the poor (Moslems or not), not to "delve into falsehood along with those who delved" (See explanation/ tafssir of Al jalalayn) and to believe in the last day.
A disbeliever deny the last day, and consequently don't pray, don't have a heart for the poors,  and tries to convince the others that religion is a lie among other things.
So Almighty Allah just mentions some of the deed of the disbelievers.
In reality they do more other sins: fornication, lies and so on.
So don't understand these verses as the sole and all deeds of the guests of  Saqar.

And of course Almighty Allah knows better. Allahou aalam

Answer (score 0):

It is up to Allah, may Allah protect us from that punishment, and forgive our sins.

But if you commit those deeds then you're at a greater risk of getting that punishment, compared to if you didn't do any of those deeds. Allah knows best.